# Error while persisting data into database in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have created an update password form and whenever I try to submit the data I got error like `The class XXX was not found in the chain configured namespaces`. What am I doing wrong in here? The error occurs when I try to save the data in the database. I have tried the answer from [implementing update password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129784/implement-change-password-in-symfony2)
Here are my codes.
This is my ChangePasswordType.php

```
<?php

namespace RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('oldPassword', 'password');
        $builder->add('newPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'retailmapping_bundle_userbundle_password_chnage';
    }
}
```

This is my ChangePassword.php

```
<?php
namespace RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints as SecurityAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ChangePassword
{
     /**
      * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
      *     message = "Wrong value for your current password"
      * )
      */
     protected $oldPassword;

     /**
      * @Assert\Length(
      *     min = 6,
      *     minMessage = "Password should by at least 6 chars long"
      * )
      */
     protected $newPassword;

    public function setOldPassword($oldPassword)
    {
        $this->oldPassword = $oldPassword;
    }

    public function getOldPassword()
    {
        return $this->oldPassword;
    }

    public function setNewPassword($newPassword)
    {
        $this->newPassword = $newPassword;
    }

    public function getNewPassword()
    {
        return $this->newPassword;
    }
}
```

This is my UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\ChangePasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function editPasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), new ChangePassword());
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($data);
            $em->flush();
            dump($form->getData());
            die;
        }

        return $this->render('User/editPassword.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved. I added this code.
`if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         
         $data = $form->getData();
         $user = $this->getUser();
   $user->setPassword($data->getNewPassword());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

By default your entity is mapped to `Entity` namespace.

[DoctrineExtension code on github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L692)

```
protected function getMappingObjectDefaultName()
{
    return 'Entity';
}
```

You need to place your `ChangePassword.php` within `Entity` folder.

UPDATE:

Similar question - [you can look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813300/symfony-error-the-class-xxx-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces-xxx)

Comment: Placed the changepassword.php file within entity folder but got error like **Class "RetailMapping\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\ChangePassword"** is not a valid entity or mapped super class. do i add the **getMappingObjectDefaultName()** function in my code??

Comment: @RajShakya you are missing `/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
 */`
at the top of your class

Comment: No, I have already checked the link and that is not relevant with my problem

Comment: @RajShakya look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820597/class-xxx-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class-after-moving-the-class-i

Comment: @RajShakya run this command `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` and show result please

Comment: I ran the command but it could not find my changepassword.php file. why?